# Confusion about the stack trace of websocketpp destruction

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, instruments, websocket++

I'm using Instrument(XCode tool) to get the stack trace of my program and i got the following result:

[image]

In this picture it shows that the destruction of

`std::__1::vector<websocketpp::transport::buffer, std::__1::allocator<websocketpp::transport::buffer> >::~vector()`

called the

`std::__1::vector<boost::asio::detail::timer_queue<boost::asio::detail::chrono_time_traits<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, boost::asio::wait_traits<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock> > >::heap_entry, std::__1::allocator<boost::asio::detail::timer_queue<boost::asio::detail::chrono_time_traits<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, boost::asio::wait_traits<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock> > >::heap_entry> >::~vector()`

However, when I dig into the source code of `websocketpp::transport::buffer`, its only member was `char const *buf` and `size_t len` showed below:

```
// defined in websocketpp/transport/base/connection.hpp

137 /// A simple utility buffer class
138 struct buffer {
139     buffer(char const * b, size_t l) : buf(b),len(l) {}
140
141     char const * buf;
142     size_t len;
143 };
```

So, why destruction of `websocketpp::transport::buffer` could cause the destruction of the `vector<boost::asio::detail::timer_queue.... ::heap_entry> >`?

**Update: 2018-10-18**

Today I used `lldb` to debug my program, found that the destruction of the `vector<boost::asio::detail::timer_queue.... ::heap_entry> >` was never be executed yet.

i feel more confused now...

Comment: The downvoter please give your reason, if my question was not clear I can provide more info

Comment: So, I take it an exception is being thrown and you don't know why?

Comment: @9301293 No, there's no exception, this is a stack trace by cpu sampling, what i don't know is the destruction sequence